# Opensense - Uses route but is directly connected

Tags: networking, router, switch, vlan, pfsense

I have the following configuration: [Network Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5smAp.png)

- Router 1 (192.168.5.1/28) with Network 192.168.1.0/24 (Opensense)
- Router 2 (192.168.5.2/28) with Network 192.168.2.0/24 (PfSense)
- Server 192.168.5.12/28 (Ubuntu)

They are all connected via VLAN and Switch.

The connection works in all directions, except Server to Router 1 Network.
Packet capture revealed this:

```
19  192.168.5.12 (00:1e:67:XX:XX:XX Server 1)   192.168.1.1 (4a:0a:94:a8:85:96 Router 1)    ICMP request, ttl=64
20  192.168.1.1 (4a:0a:94:a8:85:96 Router 1)    192.168.5.12 (ee:9e:a0:4e:22:f6 Router 2)   ICMP reply, ttl=63
```

Why does Router 1 send the packet to Router 2?

Router 2 is the default gateway of Router 1, but the server is directly in the network 192.168.5.1 and directly reachable and therefore the server should be addressed directly, right?

Ping from Server to Router 1 works.
Ping from Router 1 (and its Network) to Server works. But not the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by removing the default Gateway at Router 1 and Router 2.
It is a routing network, so it is not a problem.

But I do not understand why it does not work with Gateway..